# web service using configuration file in c#

Tags: c#-4.0

### i need help to using this below configuration in xml file to change my url web service,

```
`<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UserName" value="ova"/>
    <add key="UserPassword" value="ova"/>
    <add key="ServiceName" value="xe"/>
    <add key="ServerName" value="localhost"/>
    <add key="WebService" value="/FDC_Service/FDC_Service.asmx"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>`
```

---

and its code i need to chnange with calling server name and web service in source Code appliation, like this below

```
FDC_Service.FDC_ServiceClass asd = new FDC_Service.FDC_ServiceClass();
retval = asd.FDC_Command(database.UserName, database.UserPassword, database.ServiceName, str);
```

FDC_Service is my web service, i need help
thanks....

Answer (score 1):

I hope this answers your question

in you .cs code add

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Then in your method add

```
var username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
            var password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserPassword"];
            var serviceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"];

            FDC_Service.FDC_ServiceClass asd = new FDC_Service.FDC_ServiceClass();
            retval = asd.FDC_Command(username, password, serviceName, str);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Set the appropriate uri when instantiating:

```
ws = new wsPedidosWeb.OperacionesTiendaPortTypeClient(
         new wsPedidosWeb.OperacionesTiendaPortTypeClient.EndpointConfiguration(), 
         new uri("http://whatever")
         );
```

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is looking for the full code; like I did:

```
private static string GetServiceAddressUrlByContractName(string contractFullName)
        {
            var clientSection = WebConfigurationManager
                .GetSection("system.serviceModel/client") as ClientSection;
            var endpointList = clientSection?.Endpoints.Cast<ChannelEndpointElement>().ToList();
            return endpointList?.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Contract== contractFullName)?.Address.ToString();
        }
```